# IPAddress on OVS interface

Tags: mininet, openflow, openvswitch

I want to set an IpAddress on one of my OpenVSwitch interface. I follow the following procedure.

```
link1= net.addLink(s1,s2,port1 =1, port2 =1)
link1.intf1.setIP("10.0.1.0/31")
link1.intf2.setIP("10.0.1.1/31")
```

However, the changes do not reflect. Moreover, the interface doesn't activate and can't be seen in ovsdb-server port table.
The MAC address can be correctly set by this procedure though.

Can you please advice me on what I am doing wrong.
I am getting a feeling that setting an IP address on OVS interface is not advised.

Thanks

Comment: `link1.intf1` is going to be on the switch s1?

Comment: Yes, basically I am trying to have IP address on the source and destination interfaces of a link.

Comment: `sudo ifconfig s1 10.0.1.0` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

ovs-vsctl add-port sw0 int0 -- set interface int0 type=internal
ifconfig int0 up